# Using a list as "list of indexes" to address elements of another list

Tags: python, list

Fellow Overflowers,

In Python, I'd like to use a list as a "list of indexes" to pull elements from another list. Example:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
index = [1,2]
```

I would like to access `mylist[1][2]` (i.e, the number 6) indirectly, using `index`. I tried the syntaxes `mylist(index)` and `mylist[index]` but neither works as expected.

In essence, I would like `mylist` to act as a function whose input variable is a list of indexes and whose output values are the actual members of `mylist`.

I tried looking for a solution for a while and did not succeed. (Even figuring out how to phrase the question succinctly seems rather tricky.)

PS: I'm actually trying this when `mylist` is a NumPy array, but a solution for lists should work for arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
reduce(operator.getitem, index, mylist)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import operator
mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
index = [1,2]
val = reduce(operator.getitem, index, mylist)
print(val)
```

For NumPy arrays, there is a simpler method:

```
import numpy as np
...
myarr = np.array(mylist)
val = myarr[tuple(index)]
print(val)
```

Comment: Phew! That was fast! (as well as impossible to figure out without assistance). Thanks!

Comment: I'm very glad that numpy makes things simpler. Thanks for the code examples.